# Remove NAs from nested list data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na, nested-lists

The following really seems to be a tough nut to crack:

I have a data frame with a nested list:

```
df <- structure(list(zerobonds = c(1, 1, NA), nominal = c(20, 20, NA
), calls = list(list(c(NA, -1), 1), list(list(NA, -1), 1), NA), 
call_strike = list(list(c(NA, 90), 110), list(list(NA, 90), 
                                              110), NA), puts = list(NA, NA, list(c(NA, 1), -1)), put_strike = list(
                                                NA, NA, list(c(NA, 110), 90))), row.names = c(NA, -3L
                                                ), class = "data.frame")
df
##   zerobonds nominal     calls call_strike      puts  put_strike
## 1         1      20 NA, -1, 1 NA, 90, 110        NA          NA
## 2         1      20 NA, -1, 1 NA, 90, 110        NA          NA
## 3        NA      NA        NA          NA NA, 1, -1 NA, 110, 90
```

I want to print the structure without any `NAs` (dots instead of the blanks are ok too):

```
  zerobonds nominal calls call_strike  puts put_strike
1         1      20 -1, 1     90, 110                 
2         1      20 -1, 1     90, 110                 
3                                     1, -1    110, 90
```

I have tried all kinds of things, the best approach so far seems to be something like `rapply(df, na.omit, how = "replace")` where I can't even suppress the Warnings (`suppressWarnings` doesn't seem to work here!). `print(df, na.print = "")` doesn't help either.

I am really exhausted now, nothing seems to work... data frames in the form of nested lists doesn't seem to be a good idea after all... could anybody help?

Comment: If you remove all the NAs, then in some instances there won't be any non-NA elements. So if you want a blank, then you will have to transform your numerical variables to strings.

Comment: @tmfmnk: that would be ok, it is only about the output at the moment... could you post some code how you would approach this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
df[]<-rapply(Map(as.list,df), na.omit, how = "replace")
```

which gives

```
> df
  zerobonds nominal calls call_strike  puts put_strike
1         1      20 -1, 1     90, 110
2         1      20 -1, 1     90, 110
3                                     1, -1    110, 90
```

Comment: very elegant! I first tried it inside a function, giving back `df`, which didn't work. But when I surround it by `print` it does (any idea why? I thought that when it is given back by a function `print` is called as the default method?)... anyway: why does the `Map` work here? I nearly never use `Map`, perhaps I should...

Comment: I posted another question on this special structure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63071923/468305

Comment: @vonjd Sorry that I have no clue why is that. `Map` is a wrapper of `mapply`, the key to make it fly is to make columns of `df` as a list, so we could use `lapply` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own recursive function and apply it to each column :

```
rm_nested_na <- function(x) {
  if (is.atomic(x)) {
    na.omit(x)
  } else {
    lapply(x, rm_nested_na)
  }
}

res <- df
listcol <- sapply(res, is.list)
res[listcol] <- lapply(res[listcol], rm_nested_na)

res
```

This is clearly inefficient if the nesting is deep.

Comment: Thank you, also quite elegant! I posted another question on this special structure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63071923/468305 - perhaps some kind of recursion could also work there?