# Remove duplicate rows in nested list data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, duplicates, nested-lists

I have a data frame with a nested list:

```
df <- structure(list(zerobonds = c(1, 1, NA), nominal = c(20, 20, NA
), calls = list(list(c(NA, -1), 1), list(list(NA, -1), 1), NA), 
call_strike = list(list(c(NA, 90), 110), list(list(NA, 90), 
                                              110), NA), puts = list(NA, NA, list(c(NA, 1), -1)), put_strike = list(
                                                NA, NA, list(c(NA, 110), 90))), row.names = c(NA, -3L
                                                ), class = "data.frame")
df
##   zerobonds nominal     calls call_strike      puts  put_strike
## 1         1      20 NA, -1, 1 NA, 90, 110        NA          NA
## 2         1      20 NA, -1, 1 NA, 90, 110        NA          NA
## 3        NA      NA        NA          NA NA, 1, -1 NA, 110, 90
```

**My question**: You see that the first and second row are duplicated. I want to remove all duplicate rows in such data frames and I am looking for some general method.

**What I tried**: `duplicated` doesn't seem to work, I guess because of this special structure of a data frame with nested lists inside.

Comment: My first idea would be to "flatten" every element of the nested list into a string : for example `list(1, list(2,3))` woud become `"1;2,3"`.
And then call `duplicated` on these new flattened columns.

Comment: @py_b: sounds great, would you want to try to create an answer with some code? Much appreciated!

Comment: I made a small package some time ago to do this, as far as I remember it worked only for nested lists of depth 2 maximum.
Maybe you can have a look and take inspiration of the code if it does not fit exactly :
https://github.com/py-b/listchr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to flatten the nested lists of each column and then apply `unique`, e.g.,

```
> unique({df[]<-Map(function(x) Map(unlist,x),df);df})
  zerobonds nominal     calls call_strike      puts  put_strike
1         1      20 NA, -1, 1 NA, 90, 110        NA          NA
3        NA      NA        NA          NA NA, 1, -1 NA, 110, 90
```

Comment: Thank you (again!), I will have to wrap my head around this to see how and why this works!

Comment: @vonjd You are welcome, hope this code can help you somewhat

Comment: Is it possible in this approach that `list(1, c(2, 3))` and `list(c(1, 2), 3)` will be flattened the same way and therefore considered as duplicated, whereas they are not?

Comment: @py_b Yes, they will be flattened in the same way, reaching the same format

Comment: This is tricky, a safer way could be to use some sort of a _hash_ of a cell.

Comment: @py_b Exactly, hashing can make the `flatten` and `unique` processes play safe. We can add an extra `sort` outsides `unlist`, but the example is a special one which may not need that

Comment: How would I know whether I can use this approach? Why do you think that a hash-based approach may not be needed here? Thank you

Comment: @vonjd For example, `v1 <- c(1,2,3,2)` and `v2 <- c(2,1,3,2)` are duplicated if the order of elements doesn't matter in you application, when we need to apply hashing to make them presented in the same way, e.g., `sort(v1)` and `sort(v2)` are the same. In your example, after flattening the cells, all elements are in the same order, so you don't need do hashing again. However, if the order of elements matters, then `v1` and `v2` are distinct even though they have the same elements.